# Fragment already added

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 3 Fragments, and 3 buttons, when i click on a button, it changes fragment, but when i click on a item on a fragment list, it opens up a new fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ContactFragment.OnContactClickedListener{
private CalendarFragment calendarFragment;
private CommunicationFragment communicationFragment;
private ContactFragment contactFragment;
private SingleContactFragment singleContactFragment;
//
private FragmentManager manager;
//
private Button btn_calendar, btn_contact, btn_communication;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bind();
    initFragments();

    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fl_main_container, calendarFragment).commit();
}

private void bind() {
    btn_calendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main_calendar);
    btn_communication = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main_communication);
    btn_contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main_contact);
    btn_calendar.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_communication.setOnClickListener(listener);
    btn_contact.setOnClickListener(listener);
}

private void initFragments() {
    calendarFragment = new CalendarFragment();
    communicationFragment = new CommunicationFragment();
    contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
    singleContactFragment = new SingleContactFragment();
}

private void changeFragment(Fragment f) {
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_main_container, f).commit();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();
}
private void displayContact(ContactObject contact){
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_main_container, singleContactFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    manager.executePendingTransactions();
}
private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_main_calendar:
            changeFragment(calendarFragment);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_main_communication:
            changeFragment(communicationFragment);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_main_contact:
            changeFragment(contactFragment);
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(ContactObject contact) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    displayContact(contact);
}
}
```

When i click on Contact, i choose a contact, and i click on contact again and then i start to tap on my back button, a "IllegalStateException ; Fragment already added : ContactFragment" is thrown. And i don't see why.

Here's the logcat :

```
    07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ContactFragment{420b6a40 #0 id=0x7f060000}
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1192)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:646)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:482)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at com.big5media.ercoiffure.MainActivity.changeFragment(MainActivity.java:57)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at com.big5media.ercoiffure.MainActivity.access$1(MainActivity.java:55)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at com.big5media.ercoiffure.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-02 13:32:31.046: E/AndroidRuntime(11412):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you provide the logcat output?

Comment: Okay, i've just edited it.

Answer (score 0):

On your changeFragment method try to append with addToBackStack(null) if you do not need to navigate back... Otherwise you should better to remove fragment and add it again.

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fl_main_container, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: But the addToBackStack method is here to remember the operation, so when i backpress i return to the state before and not quit the app. But i don't want to remember.